# Добавление элементов в двумерный массив

Tags: python

Хочу добавлять числа в двумерный массив в цикле, есть вот такой код:

```
customers = [1,3,5,7,3,7,9,67]
n = 4
if len(customers) == 0:
    print(0)
elif n == 1:
    print (sum(customers))
elif n >= len(customers):
    print(max(customers))
else: #СОДЕРЖАТЕЛЬНАЯ ЧАСТЬ
    tills = [[]]*n
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(customers)):
        tills[j].append(customers[i])
        if j < n-1:
            j += 1
        else:
            j = 0

print(tills)
```

НО я не понимаю, почему вывод вот такой:

```
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 7, 9, 67], [1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 7, 9, 67], [1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 7, 9, 67], [1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 7, 9, 67]]
```

По моей логике (что и нужно получить мне), должно быть вот так:

```
[[1,3],[3,7],[5,9],[7,67]]
```

Как этого добиться?

Comment: что вы хотите? add `input` `output` `required_output` и что это прога делает.

Comment: вы ошиблись в tills = [[]]*n  вы не создали двумерный массив. вы создали эн связей на список. и изменяя любую 'копию', меняются и все остальные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В питоне списки - это объекты, и поэтому сам язык старается максимально оптимизировать их использование через ссылки, ленивые вычисления и так далее.

Когда вы создаете список с помощью кода `array = [[]] * n`, то фактически вы создаете только список `array[0]`, а все остальные списки становятся его копиями, записанными с помощью ссылки на этот созданный "нулевой" список.

Поэтому добавляя элементы в любой из списков, вы фактически добавляете эти элементы в `array[0]`, а в остальных списках они появляются потому, что все остальные списки являются ссылками на `array[0]`.

Для того, чтобы исправить данную ошибку, можно использовать генераторы списков:

```
array = [[] for _ in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте список следующим образом:

```
customers = [1,3,5,7,3,7,9,67]
n = 4
if len(customers) == 0:
    print(0)
elif n == 1:
    print (sum(customers))
elif n >= len(customers):
    print(max(customers))
else: #СОДЕРЖАТЕЛЬНАЯ ЧАСТЬ
    tills = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(customers)):
        tills[j].append(customers[i])
        if j < n-1:
            j += 1
        else:
            j = 0

print(tills)
```